# JavaScript - xmlhttprequest trae el html de una página pero no ejecuta los scripts iniciales de la misma

Tags: javascript, get, xmlhttprequest

estoy tratando de leer el html y contenido de una web por medio de xmlhttprequest, sin embargo, la página a la cual deseo obtener información debe de ejecutar unos scripts internos al abrirla los cuales creo que no los ejecuta el xmlhttprequest, y por ende en el html que me retorna me aparece un mensaje "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app" en un elemento html noscript, quiero saber si es posible ejecutar estos scripts para poder extraer el contenido.

Lo otro que se me estaba ocurriendo es utilizar el window.open para abrir fisicamente esta página, dejar que carguen los scripts y posteriormente utilizar el xmlhttprequest para extraer la info del mismo aunque no se si sea posible.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda, y disculpas por si cometí algún error en la escritura de este post, es mi primera vez.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET',"urlalaquetratodeingresar",true);

setTimeout(function(){
    
        
        xhr.responseType = 'document';
    xhr.send();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var html = xhr.response;
            console.log(html);

        }
    }

},5000);
```

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Si es posible explica qué quieres decir con *la página a la cual deseo obtener información debe de ejecutar unos scripts internos al abrirla*. Ten en cuenta que la finalidad de [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) es intercambiar datos entre el cliente y el servidor. ¿Esos scripts de los que hablas son scripts de Javascript? Si es así, no tiene sentido mandarlos a buscar con `XMLHttpRequest`, porque puedes ponerlos del lado del cliente directamente. Por otra parte, el error ...

Comment: *`You need to enable JavaScript to run this app`* significa que no tienes habilitado Javascript en tu navegador.

Comment: No puedes consumir una App que se basa en Javascrtipt usando simplemente `xhr`. En todo caso, si lo que deseas es un `scrap` del contenido de una app web, lo ideal es que uses alguna herramienta diseñada para tal tarea. Saludos